# How to make connections between two components in graphical views

Tags: scadalts

I'm trying to make a graphical representation of my Modbus states and I can't find any feature which will allow me to add connection between two components. I'm looking for some kind of wire which will change it's state depends of the holding register state.

I already tried almost every function of the ScadaLTS SW.

Comment: I do not know I understand the question well. Can you describe more precisely what states the Modbus accepts, and what should you expect to be displayed in the view (mock-up would be helpful)